# Select and show business open hours from MySQL

Tags: mysql

I dont need to check if business is open or close, but I need to show open hours by days.

There are some options:

1 - Business open once in day (sample - from 10:00 to 18:30) - one
   rows in table
2 - Business open TWICE in day (samlpe - from 10:00 to
   14:00 and from 15:00 to 18:30) - two rows in table
3 - Business may
   be closed (no row inserted)

Here my MySql table of hours storing. In this sample business **(affiliate_id)** are open twice in days from 0 to 4, once in day 5 and closed in day 6 (no records for this day)

http://postimage.org/image/yplj4rumj/

What I need to show in website its like (according to this database example:

0,1,2,3,4 - open 10:00-14:00 and 15:00-18:30
5 - open 10:00-12:00
6 - closed

How I get results like:

http://postimage.org/image/toe53en63/

?

I tried to make queries with GROUPֹ_CONCAT and LEFT JOIN the same table ON a.day=b.day but with no luck :(

There sample of my query (that is wrong)

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CAST( a.day AS CHAR ) 
ORDER BY a.day ) AS days, DATE_FORMAT( a.time_from,  '%H:%i' ) AS f_time_from, DATE_FORMAT( a.time_to,  '%H:%i' ) AS f_time_to, DATE_FORMAT( b.time_from, '%H:%i' ) AS f_time_from_s, DATE_FORMAT( b.time_to,  '%H:%i' ) AS f_time_to_s
FROM business_affiliate_hours AS a LEFT 
JOIN business_affiliate_hours AS b ON a.day = b.day
WHERE a.affiliate_id =57

GROUP BY a.time_from, a.time_to, b.time_from, b.time_to

 ORDER BY a.id ASC
```

This my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `business_affiliate_hours` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `affiliate_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `time_from` time NOT NULL,
  `time_to` time NOT NULL,
  `day` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;


INSERT INTO `business_affiliate_hours` (`id`, `affiliate_id`, `time_from`, `time_to`, `day`) VALUES
(53, 57, '10:00:00', '12:00:00', 5),
(52, 57, '15:00:00', '18:30:00', 4),
(51, 57, '10:00:00', '14:00:00', 4),
(50, 57, '15:00:00', '18:30:00', 3),
(49, 57, '10:00:00', '14:00:00', 3),
(48, 57, '15:00:00', '18:30:00', 2),
(47, 57, '10:00:00', '14:00:00', 2),
(46, 57, '15:00:00', '18:30:00', 1),
(45, 57, '10:00:00', '14:00:00', 1),
(44, 57, '15:00:00', '18:30:00', 0),
(43, 57, '10:00:00', '14:00:00', 0);
```

Open hours may be different for every day, so I want to GROUP by the same open hours, and get list of days for all unique order of open hours.

Need your help!

Sorry for links to images, I cant upload images yes to here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First build a materialised table of each day's combined times, then group on that:

```
SELECT   GROUP_CONCAT(day ORDER BY day) AS days,
         DATE_FORMAT(f1, '%H:%i') AS f_time_from,
         DATE_FORMAT(t1, '%H:%i') AS f_time_to,
         DATE_FORMAT(f2, '%H:%i') AS f_time_from_s,
         DATE_FORMAT(t2, '%H:%i') AS f_time_to_s
FROM (
  SELECT   day,
           MIN(time_from) AS f1,
           MIN(time_to  ) AS t1,
           IF(COUNT(*) > 1, MAX(time_from), NULL) AS f2,
           IF(COUNT(*) > 1, MAX(time_to  ), NULL) AS t2
  FROM     business_affiliate_hours
  WHERE    affiliate_id = 57
  GROUP BY day
) t
GROUP BY f1, t1, f2, t2
ORDER BY days
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e65e/1/0).

Comment: can you help me on that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415716/want-to-merge-two-rows-into-one-using-mysql-group-concat